# How to change the color of the dropdown text color of ttk combobox widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk, ttkwidgets

First I was trying only used:

```
missed_list_combobox.config(foreground="red")
```

Then I was trying to set new style:

```
style_missed_combobox = tkinter.ttk.Style()
style_missed_combobox.configure("Red.TCombobox", foreground="red")
```

And use it after create the combobox widget.

```
missed_list_combobox = tkinter.ttk.Combobox(frame4, state="readonly", width=32, style="Red.TCombobox")
missed_list_combobox.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=2, sticky="w", pady=3)
```

But same ...it's only change the color of the top element in the combobox...
not the entire dropdown elements...
how can i change the color text of all the dropdown element..?

Thanks in advance,
eliran

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this is not directly possible with tkinter because we cannot acccess the combobox's listbox through the python interface.
However this can be done using the underlying tcl interpreter with:

```
missed_list_combobox.tk.eval('[ttk::combobox::PopdownWindow %s].f.l configure -foreground red' % missed_list_combobox)
```

If you also want to change the background to yellow, just add `-background yellow` to the above tcl command.

By the way, if you want to change the default foreground of all comboboxes' dropdown listbox, you can use

```
root.option_add('*TCombobox*Listbox.foreground' % frame, 'red')
```

but this will only apply to comboboxes created after this line (`root` can be replaced by any widget)